# MySQL Full text search with multiple keywords

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, keyword

I have a table with a text column (VARCHAR(160)) which I want to search with multiple keywords. The problem is, and I have searched for the answer everywhere, that I wan't another column to update with keywords that are matched in that row from that column.

This is the basic code:
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (column) AGAINST ('"A1" "A2 "A3" "B1" "B2" "etc."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";`

This works in phpmyadmin (the keywords are actually longer then 4 characters) but the next step is that when a word in a row from 'column' is matched with a AGAINST keyword [an]other column[s] (e.g. keywords) is updated with for example 1 or multiple keywords (e.g. A1, B1, C4) and another column with TRUE or 1 so I know that this row has multiple matching keywords or 0 when there is only one match (e.g. A1).

How do I do this?

**To clearify:** I have multiple keywords and I wan't to know *which* keywords correspond to a certain text. I want these keywords that match to the text in a different column. This can be one keyword but also multiple (e.g. A1, B3, C2). Therefore, I want a additional second column that is either true or false (1,0) and corresponds to multiple keyword matches or a single one, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

According to (for "search with multiple keywords"): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (column) AGAINST ('+kw1 +kw2 +kw3 etc...')
```

Comment: Using '+[keyword]' is the equivalent of AND, and actually not the question I asked. To clearify: I have multiple keywords and I wan't to know which keywords correspond to a certain text. I want these keywords that match to the text in a different column. This can be one keyword but also multiple (e.g. A1, B3, C2). Therefore, I want a additional second column that is either true or false (1,0) and corresponds to multiple keyword matches or a single one, respectively.

Comment: Sorry my pure English, if you search a keyword in different columns, so you can; `where match (col1,col2,col3 etc...) against ('keyword')`. Remember, you need to define a `FULLTEXT` index that contains which columns will be searched (used in "match (col1,col2...)" part).

Comment: The column is defined as a FULLTEXT and it's a single column with multiple rows. I just wan't each row (with a single column) checked on keywords and especially WHICH keywords are matched.